# Remove Spaces when creating a file in php

Tags: php

Please i have to ask you something,

I need to remove the spaces of the file this code generates. now the original code is as below!

```
$small_file = $image->createFile(' '.$filename);
```

The point is i need that ' ' because otherwise it won't work..the code i mean! Now, what i need is something like below, which will permit me to remove the spaces generated from the code but before submission.

```
$small_file = $image->REMOVE_SPACES[createFile(' '.$filename)];

function createFile($output_filename = null) {
if($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG") {
imageJPEG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename, $this->quality);
} elseif($this->ext == "PNG") {
imagePNG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext);
} elseif($this->ext == "GIF") {
imageGIF($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext);
}
return $output_filename;
}
$filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
```

All the code:

```
function createFile($output_filename = null) {
if($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG") {
imageJPEG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename, $this->quality);
} elseif($this->ext == "PNG") {
imagePNG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext);
} elseif($this->ext == "GIF") {
imageGIF($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext);
}
return $output_filename;
}

function setUploadDir($dirname) {
$this->uploaddir = $dirname;
}

function flush() {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
$targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name']; 

imagedestroy($this->dst_r);
unlink($targetFile);
imagedestroy($this->img_r);

}

}

$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
$targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name']; 
$thumbnail = basename($filename,'.' .$ext) . $ext;
$thumbnail1 = basename($filename);      



move_uploaded_file ($tempFile, $targetFile);

 $image = new Image();
            $image->setFile($targetFile);
            $image->setUploadDir($targetPath);
            $image->resize(640);
$large_file = $image->createFile(' '.$thumbnail1);
            $image->resize(120);
$small_file = $image->createFile('s_'.$thumbnail);
            $image->flush();
}
```

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Why doesn't your code work without a space? This should work fine : `$small_file = $image->createFile($filename);` syntax wise

Comment: Yes, but it won't generate the image if i do so... the createFile function as it appears won't let this be possible

Comment: What does createFile returns? The file name?

Comment: let me update the question please so you can see by yourself

Comment: you realise that `$image->createFile()` is not the same as `$image->REMOVE_SPACES[createFile()]` right? it should be something like `$image->createFile(str_replace(" ", "", $filename))`

Comment: Hey Ckkiller, thanks for the answer..in fact now that i think better it can't be done the way i think... well! i need to modify my createFile function at all costs

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as:

```
$small_file = str_replace(' ', '', $image->createFile(' '.$filename));
```

To remove all spaces.

Or, to remove just the leading spaces:

```
$small_file = ltrim($image->createFile(' '.$filename));
```

Comment: Unfortunately it won't remove the spaces, but your code works perfect, i mean, is just that in my case it won't work..! i have to modify my createFile function in order for it to work

Comment: can you please help me with modifying my createFile function? i can't seem to make it work, i mean if i remove the ' ' it won't generate te new file!

Comment: And also, "can't seem to make it work", do you get any errors, etc?

Comment: No no, absolutely, i don't get any errors, i just can't do the rename! i mean, if i remove the ' ' then the file won't be generated!

Comment: I updated the answer with all the code, what i need is just that the $large_file to give em as an output the name of the file, without spaces or anything..simple as that..

Comment: hey can you please see my updated code? i have made some changes and i have this kind of new question, please!

Comment: This is a completely different question than the original one. Please post your new question in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can remove space from image name or replacing them with underscore "_"  

 $small_file = $image->createFile(' '.$filename);
 $small_file = str_replace(" ","_",$small_file);

It will change all space witn _ in your $small_file string.
```

Comment: Yes but, i don't need underscores... i just need the image as it is!

Comment: Ok then just replace _ with "" Like : $small_file = str_replace(" ","",$small_file);

Comment: Can you please, please see my code, i've updated my question, kind of!

Comment: Do you want to remove space from $large_file variable?  Please give me variable name or string example from where you want to remove spaces.